# Show files that includes a specific header

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

For example, I got a file named `foo.h` and I want to list files that includes this header.

I know one method is to drag-and-drop `foo.h` from Project Explorer into Include Browser windows, but it takes time since I have to search that file in Project Explorer and then drag-and-drop it.

Is there any shortcut for this features in Eclipse ? I have searched on Internet but to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type the file name, right click on the result, select "Show in->Include browser"